# Type arguments in sub class declarations

Tags: java, generics, types, arguments

I am  currently learning generics and having a hard time comprehending some aspects of them. I feel like I've overlooked something so the question might sound stupid.

I understand that there are:

1. Placeholders, known as '*formal type parameters*'.
2. Actual '*type arguments*'.

Here's a piece of sample code I have with generics and method chaining that works:

```
class Clothing <T> {
    String material; 
    String color; 

    T setMaterial (String material) {
        this.material = material;
        return (T) this;
    }

    T setColor (String color) {
        this.color = color;
        return (T) this;
    }

}

class Jeans extends Clothing <Jeans>  {

}

class Pants extends Clothing <Pants>  {

}


class Executor {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Jeans jeansPair = new Jeans().setMaterial("cotton").setColor("green");
    }

}
```

The problem is I don't understand why the type arugment such as *Jeans* and *Pants* are provided in sub-class declarations instead of instantiations like the one in the main method.

I would appreciate if you provided a link to this rule--I've looked up a lot of info such as bounded parametrs, raw types, erasure etc. but did not quite find what I was looking for.

Thanks

Comment: This is Curiously Recurring Generic Pattern, or Template Pattern in c++ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: You might want to look at this post as well http://stackoverflow.com/q/26762955/3280538

Comment: This is also a way to allow an abstract base class to perform method chaining http://www.unquietcode.com/blog/2011/programming/using-generics-to-build-fluent-apis-in-java/

Comment: @flkes Thanks, I will look into these links!

Answer (score 0):

*Aside: you'd likely have an easier time with these generics if you used a builder pattern rather than the mutable pattern you're describing here. I just [answered a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38295940/113632) that provides an example of such a builder structure.*

`Jeans` and `Pants` are concrete types without a generic parameter, which is why when constructing them you simply say `new Jeans()` / `new Pants()`; they have no generic type the caller can specify. Since they also extend a generic type, you could say:

```
Clothing<Jeans> jeans = new Jeans()....;
```

if you wanted to refer to the object by its generic parent type. This is no different than any other parent/child type relationship, such as `List<String>` vs. `ArrayList<String>`. These classes simply hard-code the value of the generic type.

You could imagine copying the methods in `Clothing` into `Jeans` and `Pants` and replacing `T` with `Jeans` and `Pants` respectively, if that helps you see the what these classes are doing.

As to *why* the type argument is provided in sub-class declarations, it's a stylistic choice, there isn't a rule about when it should be used. It's nice when you have a finite number of types that can/should be used as the generic type, since now callers don't have to explicitly specify the type every time. However in the "generic" case where a generic type represents an arbitrary number of different concrete types this pattern is detrimental, since the class author needs to define a new subclass for every given type.